# why does eval("1+7" + "6") output 77 in Python?

Tags: python

I would expect this code to print out 86 or 14

`print(eval("1+7" + "6"))`

but it prints out 77 instead. I tried finding an answer online but I couldn't really grasp why it does this.

Comment: Please explain *exactly* what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code. This includes printing the values of the intermediate expressions.  What is `"1+7"?  What is that `+ "6"`?

Comment: @Prune I think I understand it now. So Python does string concatenation before doing any integer addition/subtraction/multiplication/division. Is that right?

Comment: @slimeworm, yes. In order to pass arguments to a function, Python needs to evaluate these arguments first. So, in `print(eval("1+7" + "6"))`, the first thing that's evaluated is `t1 = "1+7" + "6"`, then `t2 = eval(t1)` and finally `t3 = print(t2)`.

Answer (score 10):

1. `"1+7" + "6" == "1+76"` (string concatenation)
2. `eval("1+76") == 1 + 76 == 77` (integer addition)

Answer (score 2):

Responding to your comment:

> Python does string concatenation before doing any integer
> addition/subtraction/multiplication/division. Is that right?

That is not right.  Python does operations in the order you dictate.  There are a few operator precedence rules, but those do not apply here.  In your code, Python must first evaluate the argument you give for the function call.  That argument is `"1+7" + "6"`, the concatenation of two string literals.  Until that is done, the argument is not ready to send to `eval`.

Had you wanted the arguments evaluated in the other order, you would have to properly specify that order -- in short, programming your intention:

```
eval("1+7") + eval("6")
```

*This* gives your expected output of `14`.

Comment: this example nails it